# Error with calling variable from a class

Tags: c++, windows, class, variables

```
class Vars{
    public:
    char *appData = getenv("AppData");
    string dir = strcat(appData, "\\Adam");
};
```

This is my class

And this is how I'm trying to use it:

```
void write(string data){
    ofstream outfile(Vars.dir + "\\data"); //here's the error
    outfile << data;
    outfile.close();
}
```

This is the error:

```
main.cpp|88|error: expected ',' or '...' before '.' token|
```

Is this not the way to call variables from a class? Classname.variable/functionname ?

EDIT: So after making instances of my Vars class, I'm getting these errors:

```
main.cpp|19|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]|
main.cpp|20|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]|
main.cpp||In function 'void write(std::string)':|
main.cpp|88|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'|
main.cpp|88|note: candidate is:|
mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\fstream|702|note: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]|
mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\fstream|702|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'|
main.cpp||In function 'std::string read(std::string)':|
main.cpp|96|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)'|
main.cpp|96|note: candidate is:|
mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\fstream|531|note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]|
mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\fstream|531|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'|
main.cpp||In function 'int read(int)':|
main.cpp|107|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)'|
main.cpp|107|note: candidate is:|
mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\fstream|531|note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]|
mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\fstream|531|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'|
main.cpp|108|error: expected ';' before 'if'|
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create an object of type Vars?

Comment: @Dolphiniac Yup! But I forgot that, and now it's all fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of the `Vars` class:

```
Vars v;
ofstream outfile(v.dir + "\\data");
```

Comment: Ohh! I completely forgot... Thanks!!!

Comment: Hm. I'm getting way more errors now!

Comment: @Adam OK, your class uses data member initialization that is only available in C++11. So compile with the `-std=c++11` flag, as the compiler suggests.

Comment: Alright, all fixed! Thank you very much!